# Pine Script - Using Swing High greater than entry for Short Trade Stop Loss

Tags: pine-script

I'm working on a strategy that uses the recent Swing High as Stop Loss points for my Short trades. However on some trades the current Swing High is lower than the close price of the candle I want to enter on, forcing the trade to stop out instantly. I want to make it so the strategy uses the most recent Swing High that is greater than the close of the candle it is entering on.

I currently use this to enter my trades and set the stop loss:

```
if isShort
   strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short)
   shortSL := swingHigh
```

The only thing I've thought of is to use the "ta.barssince" function to see how many bars back the Swing High was greater than the close of the entry candle. In a way like this:

```
barsback = ta.barssince(swingHigh < close)
```

but I don't know if there is a way to make this function compare the Swing High of previous bars to the close of the current bar.

[Short Trades Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlpU3.png)

As you can see in the linked image the first Short Trade executes as normal as the recent Swing High is greater than the close of the candle it entered on, but on the second trade executed it is stopped out immediately as the recent Swing High is below the close of the entry candle. Looking for any methods to make this work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the barssince manually using for loop like below, where you can compare current close to previous swinghighs

```
barssinc=0
for i=0 to 100
    barssinc:=barssinc+1
    if swingHigh[i] < close
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to identify the last swing in a different way, like using `ta.highest()`

In some strategies is better to fix a number of candles and set the stop loss at the highest one in this range, for example:

```
hh = ta.highest(high, 6)
```

[image]

in this example i set the SL at the swing high where you see the red line (white is the entry and green tp orders)